# Android Error undefined method instead of actually defining with the correct type parameter

Tags: android, json, image, android-asynctask, execute

I have few functions where I am having a conflict. I am using AsyncTask class in Android, to make calls to Tmdb API, so that I can retrieve images and text already stored in JSON Data.

Here is the code:

```
    public void prepareImages (SimpleAdapter adapter){
      ListView listView = new ListView(this);
      listView.setAdapter(adapter);

       for(int i=0;i<adapter.getCount();i++){
           HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(i);
           String imgUrl = (String) hm.get("flag_path");
           Display_With_Image imageLoaderTask = new Display_With_Image();

           HashMap<String, Object> hmDownload = new HashMap<String, Object>();
           hm.put("poster_path",imgUrl);
           hm.put("position", i);

           // Starting ImageLoaderTask to download and populate image in the listview
               imageLoaderTask.execute(hm);
       }

  }
```

**Got error here at last line - call for execute function:  - The method execute(HashMap) is 
     undefined for the type Display_With_Image**

The other class is:

```
    class ImageDownloading extends AsyncTask<HashMap<String, Object>, Void, HashMap<String, Object>>{

    @Override
   protected HashMap<String, Object> doInBackground(HashMap<String, Object>... hm) {

     InputStream iStream=null;

     String imgUrl = (String) hm[0].get("poster_path");
     int position = (Integer) hm[0].get("position");

     ... more code ...
```

**This method doInBackground is called when execute is actually called, I know this, but I can't solve the error, since the parameter defined is a hashmap having String, Object and so is my object "hm" in the prepareImages() function.**

Please let me know what's wrong, i only see a difference that I am passing parameter of type HashMap, but in the parameter defined it shows Hashmap with two extra dots ".."

EDIT: Display_With_Image

```
    public class Display_With_Image extends Activity {

public void displayDownloadedImages (HashMap<String, Object> result){
      // Getting the path to the downloaded image
        ListView listView = new ListView (this);
   String path = (String) result.get("poster_path");

   // Getting the position of the downloaded image
   int position = (Integer) result.get("position");

   // Getting adapter of the listview
   SimpleAdapter adapter = (SimpleAdapter ) listView.getAdapter();

   // Getting the hashmap object at the specified position of the listview
   HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(position);

   // Overwriting the existing path in the adapter
   hm.put("position_path",path);

   // Noticing listview about the dataset changes
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


  }

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_imdbsearch_result);
    //getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    // Get the intent to get the query.
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String query = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_QUERY);

}

    class ImageDownloading extends AsyncTask<HashMap<String, Object>, Void, HashMap<String, Object>>{

 @Override
 protected HashMap<String, Object> doInBackground(HashMap<String, Object>... hm) {

     InputStream iStream=null;

     String imgUrl = (String) hm[0].get("poster_path");
     int position = (Integer) hm[0].get("position");

     URL url;
     try {
         url = new URL(imgUrl);

         // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
         HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

         // Connecting to url
         urlConnection.connect();

         // Reading data from url
         iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

         // Getting Caching directory
         File cacheDirectory = getBaseContext().getCacheDir();

         // Temporary file to store the downloaded image
         File tmpFile = new File(cacheDirectory.getPath() + "/wpta_"+position+".png");

         // The FileOutputStream to the temporary file
         FileOutputStream fOutStream = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);

         // Creating a bitmap from the downloaded inputstream
         Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iStream);

         // Writing the bitmap to the temporary file as png file
         b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, fOutStream);

         // Flush the FileOutputStream
         fOutStream.flush();

        //Close the FileOutputStream
        fOutStream.close();

         // Create a hashmap object to store image path and its position in the listview
         HashMap<String, Object> hmBitmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

         // Storing the path to the temporary image file
         hmBitmap.put("flag",tmpFile.getPath());

         // Storing the position of the image in the listview
         hmBitmap.put("position",position);

         // Returning the HashMap object containing the image path and position
         return hmBitmap;

     }catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return null;
 }



@Override
 protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, Object> result) {
   displayDownloadedImages(result);
 }

 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }   
  }
 }
```

Comment: Post your `Display_With_Image`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `imageLoaderTask` is an object of `Display_With_Image` class which extends `Activity`.

`Activity` does not have an `execute` method. `AsyncTask` does.

You want to create an object of `ImageDownloading`

Change

```
Display_With_Image imageLoaderTask = new Display_With_Image();
```

to

```
ImageDownloading imageLoaderTask = new ImageDownloading();
```

then you will be able to call `execute` on `imageLoaderTask`